# Migration Endpoint when migrating Windows 2003 Exchange 2007 to Office 365

Tags: exchange-2007, microsoft-office-365, exchange-migration

I am currently migrating an Exchange 2007 environment with about 50 mailboxes to Office 365 Premium (with online Exchange).

Although setting up a staged migration is pretty straightforward, what do I need to arrange to enable my local server as a migration endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

- Add the option "RPC-over-HTTP" via the Windows Features in Add/Remove Programs
- Enable Outlook Anywhere (that is not the same as just having OWA available)
- Make sure you import a SSL certificate in the IIS website from a trusted authority, so NOT a self-signed one. The FQDN in the certificate should be that of your public FQDN (not that of the local mailserver)
- Only port 443 with TCP has to be routed via NAT to your local mailserver

A bit of detail can also be found on the MS Technet website here: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb123889%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx